# Why does yarn install node_modules folder for @types/angular* dependencies?

Tags: angular, typescript, npm, yarnpkg

If I use npm to install my dependencies there is no node_modules folder inside the @types folder.

If I use yarn every @types dependency contains a node_modules folder (`./node_modules/@types/angular-cookies/node_modules`)

This breaks my build later on because there are some inconsistencies.

My question is: Why does yarn create those folders for angular types?

I solved this problem with a .yarnclean but I'm still wondering.

Comment: npm version, yarn version ?

Comment: node v7.10.0 (npm v4.2.0), yarn 0.28.4

Comment: It may be a potential bug. Track it here. https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/4226